# In Biztalk Mapping Remove Empty Child record

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

plz find my map below.

[image]

where in my first script file i am checking if my reference type is equal to A,B,C,D,E then only the rest of the elements should map to destination schema, by doing that i am getting below output.

[image]

However i don’t want to generate empty child tags. Could you please suggest. I have checked some blogs where suggesting xslt, I have no idea of xslt so want to do with functoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try linking your Equals functoid to the PartyReference element in your output schema. The boolean output that the functoid provides should then control whether or not the element is included in the output of the map.